# Using docker-compose volumes_from option does not work

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

In `base` Dockerfile I `ADD` some directories from host machine to image.
I want to include all directories from container running on `base` image  to another one.
So I write a simple .yml file:

```
app:
   build: .
   links:
    - base
   volumes_from:
    - base

base:
   extends:
   file: docker-base.yml
   service: base
```

But when I run `docker-compose run app /bin/bash` and then `ls` in container I see no `base` directory inside container.
Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for so stupid question.

I've forgot to include `VOLUME base` instruction to `base` image Dockerfile, so other containers can't use this mount point

Answer (score 1):

you can't use extends with links and volumes_from in order to avoid implicit dependencies. See more details : [docker docs](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/extends.md#adding-and-overriding-configuration)